# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu 12.04 (with Windows 7 on another partition)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-repair

I just installed Ubuntu on my desktop which had Windows 7 installed on it. When I restart the machine after completing the installation, It directly loads windows, I don't see the grub menu.

I tried using boot-repair using the LiveCD (both recommended fixes AND fixing the MBR), it did not help.

What am I missing? I have done this at least 5 other times, on different machines, and have never faced this issue before.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info). This will provide valuable information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Download easy bcd, go to the add entry tab on the left side, then click the linux tab and wubi selection, enter the name you want it to apear as in boot menu (Ubuntu) and click add (sometimes doesnt work just click add 3 times to be sure), then reboot. :)